# Как создать контейнер произвольной формы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно сделать карту с возможностью нажимать на города, как задать контейнеру произвольную форму(обозначить границы городов)?

Comment: Как идея создать один `svg`, в котором будут несколько `path`, которые и будут иметь произвольную форму. И к ним уже прикрепить обработку `onclick`. Загуглите "css js интерактивная карта", в интернете огромная куча примеров.

Comment: Произвольную форму контейнеру можно задать при помощи clip-path. Или прибегнуть к помощи svg. Но, в Вашем случае svg Вам даст больше возможностей

Comment: Приведите пример, что Вы в итоге хотите увидеть

Comment: чтобы можно было hover повесить, при нажатии перенаправлять на другую страницу, больше скорее всего и ничего не нужно будет

Answer (score 0):

```css
#MT_GO:hover {
  fill: aqua;
}

#MT_SE:hover {
  fill: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" mapsvg:geoViewBox="14.182891 36.082376 14.576552 35.805673"
  width="916.64319" height="792.52557">
 
  <path
     d="m 524.54316,329.0085 0,3.98 -11.64,1.6 -4.53,5.57 -5.17,0.8 -1.29,-1.59 0.65,-3.98 2.59,-2.39 5.17,0 6.47,-3.98 7.75,0 z m -94.4,-89.89 3.23,5.57 3.23,1.58 1.29,4.78 3.24,2.39 0,7.96 4.52,0.8 4.53,4.76 0.65,6.37 -9.7,6.37 -12.29,0 -3.24,3.98 -2.58,0 -1.29,2.38 1.29,3.18 -9.05,6.37 -3.88,5.57 -18.75,10.33 -1.94,3.19 0.65,6.36 3.88,8.75 3.24,2.39 31.68,-3.99 10.99,-3.18 1.94,-2.38 10.35,-3.19 4.53,-3.18 2.58,2.39 -0.65,3.18 3.24,4.77 4.52,0 0.65,-2.39 5.82,-3.18 4.52,5.57 6.47,-0.8 4.53,3.18 2.59,0 1.94,-3.18 1.29,1.6 5.82,0 0,3.18 -4.53,3.98 5.17,5.57 -5.17,7.95 2.58,1.6 0.65,4.76 -1.94,2.39 -5.82,0 -3.88,-3.18 -3.88,0.79 0,3.19 3.88,1.58 -1.29,5.57 -3.88,4.77 -2.59,7.95 -5.17,1.6 -1.29,3.98 -4.53,2.38 -0.64,6.37 5.17,0.8 5.82,-3.19 3.88,0 1.29,-3.18 3.88,-0.8 1.94,-2.38 10.35,-2.39 1.94,-3.98 4.53,1.6 -0.65,2.38 7.76,0 0.65,-2.38 3.88,2.38 1.29,-3.18 5.18,1.6 1.29,-0.8 0,-6.37 3.88,-1.58 8.41,0 1.29,-2.39 4.52,-0.79 1.3,-7.16 7.12,-5.57 5.82,-1.58 5.17,-3.98 12.28,0 0.65,3.98 -9.05,-0.8 0,7.15 -4.52,7.96 1.29,8.75 -5.82,8.75 -2.59,10.33 1.94,0 1.29,-5.57 3.88,-5.56 1.94,-1.59 5.17,0 5.17,-6.36 2.59,-0.8 3.88,-9.54 3.24,-0.8 1.94,2.39 5.18,-0.8 9.06,7.15 8.4,0 2.59,4.77 3.87,2.38 -1.94,4.77 5.18,3.19 2.59,7.95 5.82,-1.59 -1.94,-1.58 0.65,-7.16 5.17,-0.8 3.88,7.96 0,12.72 2.59,0.79 1.29,-3.97 2.59,-0.79 1.3,7.15 3.88,4.77 23.28,4.77 0.64,-2.39 10.35,-4.77 5.81,3.98 9.7,2.39 1.3,1.58 -0.65,5.57 6.47,2.39 1.29,3.18 5.17,0 3.23,2.38 0,0 -1.78,7.31 -7.08,4.35 -3.19,6.09 5.31,1.74 1.77,17.85 -2.83,3.92 -14.87,0 -7.79,10.01 -11.68,0.44 -6.37,-4.79 -6.37,-2.18 -5.31,0.44 -1.77,6.09 -1.77,0 -9.91,-10.88 -12.74,-1.31 -7.43,4.79 1.06,15.67 -1.42,10.88 -2.12,4.35 -10.97,1.31 -10.27,-3.92 -2.12,0.87 -8.14,10.44 -0.35,10.44 -2.48,0.44 -14.16,-12.18 -26.2,2.17 -3.54,2.18 -13.1,23.06 -0.35,6.09 2.48,2.61 1.42,6.53 7.44,9.14 0,0 -2.12,20.01 3.9,8.27 0.35,13.48 4.6,6.09 0,3.05 -14.16,12.61 -5.66,3.04 -4.6,0.87 -5.66,-3.91 -10.27,0.44 -2.83,10 -4.6,6.52 -2.48,10.44 -10.62,11.74 -0.35,6.96 -2.25,2.81 0,0 -7.75,-0.8 -3.23,-3.17 -7.76,0.8 -9.7,-7.95 -3.24,-6.35 -9.7,-2.39 -7.12,-8.74 -14.22,-9.52 -4.53,-10.33 -3.88,-3.17 -1.29,-4.77 -2.58,-2.39 -6.47,-0.78 -4.53,-3.19 1.29,-1.58 -1.94,0 0,-1.59 4.53,-4.77 -15.52,-0.8 -12.93,-8.74 -1.94,-6.35 -5.82,-4.77 -6.47,-8.74 2.58,-15.89 -6.47,-19.87 -7.11,-4.77 -5.82,-8.74 0,-5.56 3.88,-3.97 0.65,-4.77 -5.17,-7.94 0,-5.56 13.58,3.18 15.52,-0.8 -0.65,-3.18 -3.88,-0.8 -1.94,-4.77 1.29,-1.59 -0.65,-3.18 -5.82,-3.18 -0.65,-3.97 -5.17,-0.8 -1.94,-10.34 1.94,-14.3 2.59,-3.19 6.46,0 4.52,0.8 5.82,7.95 2.59,0 0.65,-2.38 1.94,0.8 -1.29,-5.57 1.29,-8.74 -9.7,0.8 -1.94,-7.16 0.65,-2.38 13.58,0.8 1.29,-2.39 -4.52,0 -1.29,-3.18 0,-4.77 4.53,-2.38 -1.29,-3.19 -10.35,1.59 -4.53,-4.77 1.29,-1.59 -1.29,-1.58 -5.82,-2.39 -12.29,-1.58 -3.88,-8.75 1.29,-7.95 6.46,-3.97 9.7,0 0,-8.75 4.52,-3.19 0,-6.36 7.76,-4.77 0,-2.39 -4.52,0 -2.58,-2.38 1.29,-6.37 -3.23,-5.56 3.88,0 0.65,-2.39 -8.4,-3.98 -1.29,-3.98 1.29,-2.38 3.88,0 1.29,-3.99 -2.59,-3.98 -1.29,-7.95 -16.81,-0.8 -5.82,3.98 -7.12,0 -7.75,-3.98 -3.24,-6.36 3.88,-3.98 1.29,-7.17 3.24,-6.36 4.52,-3.98 7.12,0 6.46,-11.94 3.24,0 0.64,1.6 2.59,-0.8 1.29,-5.56 -14.22,-4.77 1.94,-10.35 3.88,-0.8 -0.65,3.98 -1.94,1.6 2.58,3.18 11.64,-1.58 7.76,3.98 3.88,0 1.94,-2.39 4.53,-0.8 9.05,3.98 -1.94,-3.98 1.29,-2.38 7.76,0 4.52,3.98 1.94,-13.53 7.12,0 1.94,0.8 1.29,4.78 5.81,0 2.59,-7.17 10.35,0.8 0.65,-1.58 -6.46,-3.19 -0.65,-7.95 3.24,-3.18 8.4,3.18 -0.65,-5.57 2.52,-1.65 z"
     title="Northern"
     id="MT_NO" />
  <path
     d="m 713.35316,433.1885 4.53,0.8 3.88,5.56 -5.17,4.78 0.65,2.38 3.23,-0.8 2.58,1.59 3.23,-2.38 2.59,2.38 -3.88,3.18 0,5.57 2.59,0 -0.65,11.92 -5.82,0.8 0,2.39 2.59,0.78 0,3.19 3.88,3.18 3.23,0 2.59,-1.6 0,-7.15 1.94,-0.79 10.35,3.97 6.46,5.57 4.53,1.59 -0.65,7.95 5.82,2.38 2.59,7.16 9.05,3.17 0.65,3.18 -4.53,3.18 -4.53,0 -9.69,-4.76 -0.65,-2.39 -4.53,-2.38 -6.46,0 -10.35,5.55 -1.29,4.77 13.58,-1.58 8.4,3.18 -0.65,7.15 -5.17,3.18 -5.82,-0.79 -1.29,-2.39 -5.18,-2.38 -6.46,0 4.53,6.35 3.23,0 1.94,2.39 0,7.15 -5.82,3.17 0,5.57 0,0 -2,9.94 0,0 -9.92,5.65 -6.01,-3.04 -1.77,-4.35 -9.56,-1.74 -5.31,10.44 -2.83,0.44 -7.44,10 -2.12,0.44 -7.79,-6.09 -16.64,-4.35 -8.5,0 -13.45,-6.97 -2.83,2.18 -2.48,10.88 -3.18,1.73 -10.63,-1.73 -9.2,1.73 -5.66,-1.3 -13.81,0.87 -19.47,11.75 -4.96,-0.44 -13.1,-5.22 -6.72,1.31 -11.33,-3.92 0,0 -7.44,-9.13 -1.41,-6.53 -2.48,-2.61 0.35,-6.09 13.1,-23.06 3.54,-2.18 26.2,-2.17 14.16,12.18 2.48,-0.43 0.35,-10.45 8.15,-10.44 2.12,-0.87 10.27,3.92 10.97,-1.31 2.12,-4.35 1.42,-10.88 -1.06,-15.67 7.43,-4.78 12.75,1.3 9.91,10.88 1.77,0 1.77,-6.09 5.31,-0.44 6.37,2.18 6.37,4.79 11.69,-0.44 7.79,-10.01 14.86,0 2.84,-3.91 -1.77,-17.85 -5.31,-1.74 3.18,-6.09 7.08,-4.36 z"
     title="Central"
     id="MT_CE" />
  <path
     d="m 836.86316,724.7885 0.39,-8.51 -4.96,-5.65 -2.48,-8.26 -12.03,-12.61 -13.46,-4.78 -1.77,-6.52 -2.12,-0.87 -1.06,-6.52 -12.39,-17.4 -10.27,-20.44 -13.81,-5.21 -8.49,-6.53 -6.73,0.87 -10.62,5.22 -2.48,3.48 -4.95,0.44 -2.84,-10.88 -8.14,-1.74 -4.25,-5.65 -8.49,-3.05 -5.31,-4.78 0,-2.61 4.95,-2.17 -9.91,-9.14 1.42,-4.78 9.2,-13.49 8.14,-5.22 8.15,-0.87 5.31,-6.09 3.89,0 1.77,-1.74 2.48,-6.96 -4.6,-3.48 0,0 2,-9.94 0,0 4.52,-0.8 3.88,-5.55 3.23,0 1.95,-3.19 2.59,0 2.58,-4.77 2.59,0 1.94,-3.18 5.81,-0.79 4.53,-4.77 7.12,1.59 6.46,-4.77 3.88,0 -2.58,16.69 -2.59,2.39 -5.82,0 -1.94,1.58 -4.53,5.57 0,3.17 -4.53,2.39 -4.52,11.12 -3.88,3.19 -5.82,1.58 -3.88,6.37 -5.82,1.58 1.94,4.77 3.88,0 3.88,-3.98 1.94,0 1.94,-4.77 9.7,-1.58 5.17,-3.18 3.89,2.39 1.93,5.56 1.94,0 1.95,7.15 0.64,-4.77 -7.76,-19.86 8.41,2.38 5.81,8.74 2.59,0 -2.59,-10.33 -3.23,-3.18 1.3,-2.38 5.81,7.15 12.29,3.17 0,-1.58 -3.23,0 -5.18,-7.94 3.24,-4.77 4.52,-0.8 -6.47,-6.36 0.66,-3.18 -1.95,-5.56 1.95,-1.59 5.81,3.18 1.94,4.77 1.95,-2.39 5.17,0 4.53,3.19 3.23,0 3.88,3.97 6.46,-0.8 3.23,2.38 3.88,0 13.58,15.11 9.7,2.37 5.83,9.54 3.23,0 3.23,3.18 0.65,6.36 7.76,0.8 7.75,4.76 14.23,18.27 3.88,1.59 3.88,9.54 7.11,5.56 -0.64,2.38 -7.12,0 -2.58,2.39 -7.77,-1.59 -3.87,4.76 -7.76,0 -2.59,2.38 0,2.39 2.59,0 0.64,-1.59 9.06,-0.8 0.64,-2.38 5.17,-0.79 7.77,4.76 3.23,4.77 5.17,0.8 0,1.58 -7.76,5.56 -3.88,6.36 -5.17,0.79 -5.82,3.97 0.65,1.59 -4.53,0 -3.23,3.17 -0.65,4.77 3.24,3.19 2.58,1.58 11.64,0.79 -1.29,5.57 -1.95,0 -0.64,2.37 -2.59,0 -1.29,6.36 1.94,0 1.94,3.97 5.17,2.38 3.24,4.77 0,3.17 -7.77,3.98 -5.81,-8.74 -8.41,-1.59 -3.88,3.97 2.59,6.36 -5.82,0 -1.94,3.17 1.29,5.57 8.41,2.37 0.64,1.59 -4.52,7.15 0.64,4.76 3.88,4.77 -0.64,6.34 -1.94,0.8 -0.65,6.36 -5.17,-0.8 5.17,3.97 0,3.17 -4.53,0 1.3,7.94 -5.17,0 -1.95,-3.17 -0.64,-7.15 -4.53,-5.56 1.3,-10.32 -3.24,-2.38 -9.05,-24.61 -3.88,-3.97 -12.28,-3.18 -0.65,2.38 2.58,7.94 2.59,0 -1.29,3.97 2.58,6.36 -3.88,7.14 z"
     title="Southern"
     id="MT_SO" />
  <path
     d="m 731.40316,548.8485 4.6,3.48 -2.48,6.96 -1.77,1.74 -3.89,0 -5.31,6.09 -8.15,0.87 -8.14,5.22 -9.2,13.49 -1.42,4.78 9.91,9.14 -4.95,2.17 0,2.61 5.31,4.78 8.49,3.05 4.25,5.65 8.14,1.74 2.84,10.88 4.95,-0.44 2.48,-3.48 10.62,-5.22 6.73,-0.87 8.49,6.53 13.81,5.21 10.27,20.44 12.39,17.4 1.06,6.52 2.12,0.87 1.77,6.52 13.46,4.78 12.03,12.61 2.48,8.26 4.96,5.65 -0.39,8.51 0,0 -2.59,-0.79 -7.11,-9.53 -9.7,2.37 -7.76,0 1.94,2.39 -2.59,3.97 5.17,0 1.95,9.53 -1.95,2.38 -10.34,0.8 3.23,9.52 1.94,0.8 0,4.77 2.59,0 1.3,-3.19 5.81,-2.38 12.28,13.5 5.83,0.79 -1.94,-4.76 -3.89,-3.18 -1.93,-5.55 9.7,0 7.76,7.14 0.64,6.35 5.82,-3.18 1.3,0 0,2.39 -2.59,0.8 -7.11,8.73 -4.53,-5.56 -1.94,12.7 -8.41,5.56 0,2.38 -5.17,1.59 -3.23,3.17 -5.17,0 -4.53,3.97 -21.34,-1.59 -2.59,-1.58 -12.28,2.37 -10.99,-2.37 -3.24,-3.17 -5.81,-0.8 -11,-7.15 -2.59,0 -0.64,-2.38 -4.53,0 -1.94,-2.39 -6.46,-0.78 -3.88,-2.39 -12.93,-0.79 -1.3,1.59 -5.82,0 -5.17,-2.38 -1.94,-3.18 -3.88,0.79 -0.65,2.39 -5.82,-1.59 -0.64,2.38 -7.12,0 0,-2.38 -2.58,0 -0.65,-1.59 -4.53,0.79 0,-1.59 -4.52,0 -8.41,-8.73 -12.29,-0.79 -7.11,-2.38 -0.64,-1.58 -0.65,1.58 -2.59,-0.8 0,2.39 -1.94,1.58 -7.11,0 -25.86,-12.7 -3.24,0 -2.58,2.38 -10.35,-10.32 -17.46,-1.58 -7.11,-2.39 -9.06,0 -7.76,-3.97 -3.87,-8.73 0,-5.56 -13.58,-2.38 -10.99,-4.77 -2.59,3.18 -3.23,-4.77 -3.23,-1.58 0.64,-1.59 -7.76,0.79 -3.88,-2.39 -3.23,-11.11 -5.83,-0.79 -5.17,-7.94 0,0 2.25,-2.81 0.36,-6.96 10.62,-11.74 2.47,-10.44 4.61,-6.52 2.83,-10 10.26,-0.44 5.67,3.92 4.6,-0.87 5.66,-3.05 14.17,-12.61 0,-3.04 -4.61,-6.09 -0.35,-13.48 -3.89,-8.27 2.12,-20.01 0,0 11.33,3.92 6.72,-1.31 13.1,5.22 4.96,0.44 19.47,-11.75 13.81,-0.87 5.66,1.3 9.2,-1.73 10.63,1.73 3.18,-1.73 2.48,-10.88 2.83,-2.18 13.45,6.97 8.5,0 16.64,4.35 7.79,6.09 2.12,-0.44 7.44,-10 2.83,-0.44 5.31,-10.44 9.56,1.74 1.77,4.35 6.01,3.04 z"
     title="South Eastern"
     id="MT_SE" />
  <path
     d="m 321.50316,192.9485 3.88,3.99 0,3.18 1.94,0.8 0,4.78 -4.52,-4.78 -6.47,1.58 -4.53,-4.78 0,-3.18 9.7,-1.59 z m 43.33,-15.11 3.23,3.98 -1.29,3.98 4.53,5.57 7.11,0 12.28,13.53 1.94,4.78 -3.88,5.56 -0.64,3.98 -7.76,-0.79 -10.99,2.38 -0.65,1.6 -4.53,-0.8 -1.29,1.6 -9.05,-1.6 -2.59,1.6 1.94,0.79 -0.65,1.6 -14.87,-0.8 -5.18,2.39 -5.17,0 6.47,-8.75 5.82,-3.98 0.65,-3.19 -0.65,-3.18 -3.88,1.6 -1.94,-1.6 -0.65,-3.98 -3.88,-1.6 -3.23,-7.96 1.94,-3.18 -4.52,-3.98 1.94,-5.57 8.41,1.6 2.58,-3.98 4.53,0 1.94,5.56 1.94,-5.56 3.88,0 4.53,3.18 4.52,0.8 1.94,3.98 0,-8.76 5.17,-0.8 z m -237.96,-177.5699963 3.88,3.18 6.47,0 5.82,2.38 11.64,-0.8 1.29,1.6 6.47,0 0,3.19 -2.59,0.8000003 0,2.4 3.24,2.38 12.93,1.6 1.29,5.57 -1.93,3.99 0.64,3.18 3.89,0 1.94,-6.38 1.29,0.8 0.65,-1.6 7.12,0 3.23,3.19 3.88,0 10.35,11.15 0.65,6.38 3.24,3.98 8.4,2.38 1.29,4.78 7.75,2.4 1.94,3.98 6.46,-0.8 7.12,-12.74 6.47,-0.8 1.94,3.98 2.58,0 2.59,7.96 2.59,2.4 5.81,0.79 7.12,9.56 5.17,-0.8 7.76,-4.77 12.29,1.59 1.94,3.98 1.3,15.14 4.53,1.59 0.65,6.38 3.88,0 3.23,-3.18 9.06,3.18 5.17,9.559996 24.57,24.68 3.88,7.17 1.29,8.76 -5.17,4.77 -10.34,1.6 -4.52,5.58 -11,0.8 -5.82,7.16 -10.99,0 -3.23,-3.18 -5.17,-0.8 -5.82,0 0,1.6 -5.17,0.79 -4.53,0 -3.88,-3.18 -2.58,0 -2.59,3.18 -5.17,-1.58 -1.3,4.78 5.17,0.79 -20.04,15.13 -5.82,0 -1.94,-1.6 -3.23,1.6 -0.65,3.98 -4.53,1.6 -13.57,-0.8 -1.94,4.78 -16.17,-3.18 -5.82,5.56 -13.57,4.78 -5.17,4.78 0,2.39 -1.94,0 -6.47,-7.97 -8.4,0 -5.82,-11.14 -14.22,0 -3.24,-2.39 -15.51,0 -2.58,-2.38 -8.41,0 -2.58,-3.18 -3.88,0.8 -3.88,-1.6 0,-1.6 -8.4,1.6 0,1.6 -3.88,0 -1.29,2.38 -6.47,-3.18 0.65,-2.39 -5.17,1.6 -3.88,-6.37 -2.59,0 -1.29,-3.98 -8.4,-8.76 0,-7.16 -7.76,-7.16 -7.76,0.79 1.94,-1.58 -5.82,-3.19 -10.99,0 -2.59,3.19 -3.23,-0.8 -5.82,1.6 0,-1.6 -1.94,0.8 -8.4,-5.58 -3.23,0.8 -4.53,-5.58 0,-4.78 7.12,-7.96 -1.29,-3.98 1.29,-7.16 -3.24,-9.559996 0.65,-2.39 3.88,-0.8 0.65,-3.18 -1.94,-2.38 -2.58,0 -1.29,-8.76 8.4,-8.76 0.65,-3.98 -2.59,-11.95 -8.4,-3.98 -5.17,0 -0.65,-1.59 -1.94,-22.3 2.59,-8.76 7.12,1.59 12.93,0 1.94,-1.59 10.99,0.8 5.17,-3.98 3.88,-7.18 7.76,0 8.4,-3.9800003 9.05,0 11,-2.38 3.23,3.18 4.52,0 3.24,-6.38 3.88,0 6.47,3.98 5.82,0 1.94,-4.77 6.47,0 1.94,1.59 8.28,-1.67 z"
     title="Gozo"
     id="MT_GO" />
     <a href="#"><text fill="red" x="100px" y="100px">Ghawdex</text></a>
     <a href="#"><text fill="red" x="670px" y="730px">Iz-Zurrieq</text></a>
</svg>
```

Если я правильно поняла Вашу задачу, то вот Вам пример. Возможно, не самый удачный, но принцип Вы должны понять. Наведите на подписанные области. Увидите, что произойдет).